# How to find for how many second a push button pressed attached to microcontroller

Tags: arm, microcontroller, pic, firmware

I am new on the controller. I want to interface a microcontroller with push button. How I find the time of button is pressed. when we press button for one second it one LED is glow and similar for two second two led is glow. Thanks for your support in advance.

Idea how to implement and code for PIC or STM controller.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question. Show what you have by now, what you tried, and where specifically you stumble. This is neither a code writing service nor a discussion forum.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typically you would configure one of the microcontroller's Timer peripherals to measure time.  There are many ways to use a Timer peripheral.  For example, one way is to setup a free running timer counter to count at a fixed rate such as 100 milliseconds.  Then read the counter value when the button is pushed and again when released.  The change in the timer counter value while the button was pushed represents the length of time that the button was pushed.

Comment: ButtonPress: Start a timer; ButtonRelease: Stop the timer

Comment: If you're using an STM32 (with CubeIDE), a default project will typically have a sysTick timer set up for you. Just call `HAL_GetTick()` to get the value. It counts in milliseconds.

Comment: Have you ever written bare metal code for handling button press with microcontrollers?